# Drawable.createFromPath(filePath) returning null although the file exist

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have this code:

```
String filePath = getActivity().getFileStreamPath("into11.png").getAbsolutePath();
        if(Drawable.createFromPath(filePath)!=null){
        img.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(filePath));
        }
        else{
        Log.d("nulllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll","yessssssssssssssssssssssssssss");  
        }
```

the filepath is getting the right path of the image "data/data/.../intro11.png" but Drawable.createFromPath(filePath) is null so what's the cause of this?

Comment: Where is your file located...?

Comment: it's in my drawable folder in res and its path is /data/data/packagename/files/into11.png

Comment: try to use URI instead: Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(filePath);
  img.setImageURI(uri);

Comment: @moh.sukhni same problem

Comment: first check if the URI is not null?  if not null then try to invalidate the UI.

Comment: @User have you checked my answer ?

Comment: Have you checked the Image File in your Files Directory ?
Because files directory is different from draw-able directory.

Comment: @SalmanKhakwani I am sorry didn't see it will check it..

Comment: @SalmanKhakwani yes I didn't add this path I got it while doing getActivity().getFileStreamPath("into11.png").getAbsolutePath(); so it should exist in the files folder

Comment: @SalmanKhakwani same problem null

Comment: Okies, i have 2 questions:
1. Is your image present at `/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/files/info11.png`.
2. Have you initialized your ImageView properly ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and for me I was trying to make a Drawable from a file that I had previously saved to internal storage. My problem ended up being that my file was incorrectly saved so it didn't create the drawable. It also threw errors in the debug console.

I hope this helps somebody.

This was my code to save (The bit commented out is what I was missing):

```
URL url = new URL(remoteFile);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.connect();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
FileOutputStream fos = mainActivity.openFileOutput(filename,            
Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
byte[] byteArray = outStream.toByteArray();
fos.write(byteArray);
fos.close();
```

I'd still like to know to just save files byte by byte so I don't have to open the image and recompress it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
File drawableFile = new     File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/into11.png");

    if(Drawable.createFromPath(drawableFile.getAbsolutePath())!=null){
    img.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(drawableFile.getAbsolutePath()));
    }
    else{
    Log.d("nulllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll","yessssssssssssssssssssssssssss");  
    }
```

I hope this helps and solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

User [moh.suhkni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001446/moh-sukhni) posted a comment in the original question that *almost* completely solved it for me.

He posted:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(filePath);
img.setImageURI(uri);
```

The solution that I ended up needing was:

```
final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
final String path = uri.getPath();
final Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(path);
img.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Because for some reason this wasn't working:

```
final Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(url);
// drawable ended up being null
img.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Android's [Drawable.createFromPath()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#createFromPath(java.lang.String)) method must not like paths beginning with `file://`, as mine did. Using [Uri.parse()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse(java.lang.String)) fixed that issue for me.

Hope that this can help!

Answer (score -1):

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.smiley);
```

To show it in image view

```
ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
i.setImageResource(R.drawable.smiley);
```

or in your xml file

```
<ImageView   
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/smiley"/>
```

Comment: I know this method thanks but I don't want to use it as I am adding images in a viewpager and this method is causing time out error so I saw that someone tried to use the createfrompath... and it worked...

Comment: I believe the idea is to provide a way to load the Drawable, without providing the ID, but the path of the drawable. So you could potentially load in a very dynamic and flexible way these drawables.