# A button which allows an image to be shown in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am building my application using Android Studio, this app can upload an image from raspberry to my emulator. It works fine. What I want to do now is uploading this image and showing it directly to the user without searching it in the gallery. I thought about creating another class and setting this image as a background image in my xml file, but this is too much like I have to create another class every time I want to upload an image from my raspberry. 
Can someone help me please. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you'd like to load an image from the Android filesystem into your app and display it to the user.

[`Drawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html), Android's generalized image class, allows you to load from file via [`Drawable#createFromPath`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#createFromPath%28java.lang.String%29).

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130464/drawable-createfrompathfilepath-returning-null-although-the-file-exist) suggests `Drawable#createFromPath` doesn't work on paths beginning with `file://`, so depending on your use case you may want to precede that with [`Uri#parse`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#parse(java.lang.String))/[`Uri#getPath`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#getPath()).

Once you have a `Drawable`, you can display it in one of two ways: put an `ImageView` in your app and call its [`setImageDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) method, or set the `Drawable` as your background image via [`View#setBackground`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) (note that `setBackground` was only added in API 16 - in prior versions, you should call [`View#setBackgroundDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))).

Putting all of this together, we end up with the following (untested):

```java
private void loadImage(String imagePath) {
    Uri imageUri;
    String fullImagePath;
    Drawable image;
    ImageView imageDisplay;

    imageUri = Uri.parse(imagePath);
    fullImagePath = imageUri.getPath();
    image = Drawable.createFromPath(fullImagePath);

    imageDisplay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageDisplay);
    /*if image is null after Drawable.createFromPath, this will simply
      clear the ImageView's background */
    imageDisplay.setImageDrawable(image);

    /*if you want the image in the background instead of the foreground,
      comment the line above and uncomment this bit instead */
    //imageDisplay.setBackground(image);
}
```

You should be able to modify this to work with any `View` just by replacing `imageDisplay`'s declared type with the appropriate `View` type and changing the cast on `findViewById`. Just make sure you're calling `setBackground`, not `setImageDrawable`, for a non-`ImageView` `View`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it seems correct, but it says cannot resolve imageDisplay in this one : imageDisplay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageDisplay);

Comment: `R.id.imageDisplay` is the `ImageView`'s ID. You need to replace that with whatever name you gave your own `ImageView`.